# Reproducing simple example for Kernel PCA with Poly Kernel

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to reproduce the results from [this Wikipedia example about Kernel PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_principal_component_analysis#Example)

Here is a minimal code sample to reproduce. You should be able to copy-paste the code and execute it as long as you have all the libraries installed.

```py
import math
from random import uniform
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero
from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA


def circular_points(r, n=100):
    return [(math.cos(2 * math.pi / n * x) * r, math.sin(2 * math.pi / n * x) * r) for x in range(n)]


def noisy_points(points, a=0.2):
    return [p[0] + uniform(-a, a) for p in points], \
           [p[1] + uniform(-a, a) for p in points]


def get_sublist(points, start, end):
    return [x for x, _ in points[start:end]], [y for _, y in points[start:end]]


def plot(name, points_a, points_b, points_c):
    fig = plt.figure(name)
    ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)

    ax.plot(points_a[0], points_a[1], 'o', color='#BA2A27')
    ax.plot(points_b[0], points_b[1], 's', color='#3C75B7')
    ax.plot(points_c[0], points_c[1], 'd', color='#F6A022')
    fig.add_subplot(ax)


def main():
    blue_points = noisy_points(circular_points(1, 50))
    red_points = noisy_points(circular_points(4, 50))
    yellow_points = noisy_points(circular_points(7, 50))

    pca_points = [(p[0], p[1]) for p in zip(blue_points[0], blue_points[1])]
    pca_points += [(p[0], p[1]) for p in zip(red_points[0], red_points[1])]
    pca_points += [(p[0], p[1]) for p in zip(yellow_points[0], yellow_points[1])]
    pca_points = np.array(pca_points)

    poly_kernel_pca = KernelPCA(n_components=2, kernel='poly', degree=2, coef0=1)
    poly_pcs = poly_kernel_pca.fit_transform(pca_points)

    rbf_kernel_pca = KernelPCA(n_components=2, kernel='rbf', gamma=0.1)
    rbf_pcs = rbf_kernel_pca.fit_transform(pca_points)

    poly_blue_pcs = get_sublist(poly_pcs, 0, 50)
    poly_red_pcs = get_sublist(poly_pcs, 50, 100)
    poly_yellow_pcs = get_sublist(poly_pcs, 100, 150)

    rbf_blue_pcs = get_sublist(rbf_pcs, 0, 50)
    rbf_red_pcs = get_sublist(rbf_pcs, 50, 100)
    rbf_yellow_pcs = get_sublist(rbf_pcs, 100, 150)

    plot('Initial Points', blue_points, red_points, yellow_points)
    plot('Poly Kernel', poly_blue_pcs, poly_red_pcs, poly_yellow_pcs)
    plot('RBF Kernel', rbf_blue_pcs, rbf_red_pcs, rbf_yellow_pcs)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Where the Kernel PCA with RBF works as expected, the Poly Kernel barely changes the initial point cloud. The result from Wikipedia looks like this:

[image: Kernel PCA Result]

Note that they have used the Kernel *k(x,y)= (x^T y + 1)^2*, which from my understanding corresponds to a degree=2 and coef0=1 in scikit-learn.
Does anyone have an idea what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Wikipedia claim that the Kernel used in the example is the polynomial Kernel is wrong.

If you use the kernel

[eq1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7PPf.gif)

```
K(x,y) = x.T y + |x|²|y|²
```

the output seems to the one in the example. This kernel comes from the featue map

[eq1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwJ37.gif)

```
phi((x1, x2)) = (x1, x2, x1² + x2²)
```

which includes the polar coordinate `r=x1² + x2²`.

You can use this kernel in Scikit-learn specifying the kernel='precomputed' option in KernelPCA and passing the kernel matrix to the fit_transform function.